# Swift Penguins error: CCPhysicsNode doesn't have a member called 'space'

Tags: ios, swift

I have this error when I try this part of the code.

> error: CCPhysicsNode doesn't have a member called 'space'

```
if (energy > 5000) {
    _physicsNode!.space.addPostStepBlock({
        self.sealRemoved(nodeA)
    }, key:nodeA)
}
```

I tried a lot of alternatives but seems like nothing works for me here. I don't know what's the core problem here. Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to import "CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h" in /Supporting Files/Bridging-Header.h

I just finished that tutorial a week ago.. hope it helps.